# filtering in Azure SAQL if an element does not exist in the input data

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to write an `SAQL` on the data which is coming from event Hub in `json` format.

The input to the `azure Stream Analytics` job is as shown below.

```
{"ver":"2019-12-28 18:41:45.4184730","Data":"Data01","d":{"IDNUM":"XXXXX01","Time1":"2017-12-20T00:00:00.0000000Z","abc":"610000","efg":"0000","XYZ":"00000","ver":"2017-12-20T18:41:45.4184730Z"}}
{"ver":"2019-12-28 18:41:45.4184730","Data":"Data01","d":{"IDNUM":"XXXXX02","Time1":"2017-12-20T00:00:00.0000000Z","abc":"750000","efg":"0000","XYZ":"90000","ver":"2017-12-20T18:41:45.4184730Z"}}
{"ver":"2017-01-01 06:28:52.5041237","Data":"Data02","d":{"IDNUM":"XXXXX03","acc":-10.7000,"PQR":35.420639038085938,"XYZ":139.95817565917969,"ver":"2017-01-01T06:28:52.5041237Z"}}
{"ver":"2017-01-01 06:28:52.5041237","Data":"Data02","d":{"IDNUM":"XXXXX04","acc":-8.5999,"PQR":35.924240112304688,"XYZ":139.6097412109375,"ver":"2017-01-01T06:28:52.5041237Z"}}
```

In the first two rows, the attribute **Time1** is available where as in last two rows Time1  attribute itself is not present.

I have to store the data into cosmos DB based on the **Time1** attribute in the input data.

```
Path in json data >>> input.d.Time1.
```

I have to store data which are having **Time1** into a `cosmosDB` container and data which are not having **Time1** into another container.

I tried with the below `SAQL`.

```
SELECT [input].ver,
    [input].Data,
    d.*
INTO [cosmosDB01]
FROM [input] PARTITION BY PartitionId
WHERE [input].Data is not null
AND [input].d.Time1 is not null

SELECT [input].ver,
    [input].Data,
    d.*
INTO [cosmosDB01]
FROM [input] PARTITION BY PartitionId
WHERE [input].Data is not null
AND [input].d.Time1 is null
```

Is there any other ways like IS `EXISTS` keyword in `stream analytics` query ?

Comment: hi,Antony,any updates here?

Comment: I am getting output for the below query.
```SELECT [input].ver,
    [input].Data,
    d.*
INTO [cosmosDB01]
FROM [input] PARTITION BY PartitionId
WHERE [input].Data is not null
AND [input].d.Time1 is null
```
even though the field d.Time doesn't exists.

Comment: @Jay Gong- I am getting output for the above query, but watermark is getting increased drastically and SU utilization becomes 90% and count of backlogged input is also increasing.. Provided enough SU and RU, but still facing the issues. Is that because of the SAQL written above?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge,there is no `is_exists` or `is_defined` sql built-in keyword in ASA so far. You have to follow the way you mentioned in the question to deal with multiple outputs scenario.

(Similar case:[Azure Stream Analytics How to handle multiple output table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059617/azure-stream-analytics-how-to-handle-multiple-output-table))

Surely,you could submit feedback to ASA team to push the progress of ASA.